# Spark Merge schema, correcting datatypes (timestamp, string)

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-schema

I was reading a spark DF with options below:

```
testDF = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true") \
        .option("mergeSchema", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("folderPath/*/*")
```

However, this fails because one of the col (Date) is of type timestamp in some source files and is of type string in some files.
I don't have control over the data producers, so wanted to know how can I handle this while processing.

Challenge is it's randomly either timestamp or string across files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using spark to read parquet file, one of the advantages is that you can use schema-on-read on the fly approach, which means that you can declare the schema when you read the data. You can:

```
schema = types.StructType([
    types.StructField('date', types.TimestampType()),
    ... # declartion of other columns
])

testDF = spark.read.format("parquet")\
    .option('mergeSchema', 'true')\
    .schema(schema=schema)\
    .load("folderPath/*/*")
```

Answer (score 1):

One common approach which works for both: datetime as string and datetime as TimestampType or DateType is to explicitly convert the column to date or time.

Import string type:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("/content/sample_data/datetime_str.parquet")

df.show(truncate=False)
[Out]:
+---------------+---------+
|datetime_col   |date_col |
+---------------+---------+
|20221103191500 |20221103 |
+---------------+---------+

df.printSchema()
[Out]:
root
 |-- datetime_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_col: string (nullable = true)
```

Convert to datetime type:

```py
df = df.withColumn("datetime_col", F.to_timestamp("datetime_col", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
df = df.withColumn("date_col", F.to_date("date_col", "yyyyMMdd"))

df.show(truncate=False)
[Out]:
+--------------------+-----------+
|datetime_col        |date_col   |
+--------------------+-----------+
|2022-11-03 19:15:00 |2022-11-03 |
+--------------------+-----------+

df.printSchema()
[Out]:
root
 |-- datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

The conversion has no effect, if the column is already a TimestampType or DateType.